# Создание словаря из списка слов

Tags: python-3.x

Дан список слов, русских и английских:

```
lst=(word, music,sky,компьютер,жизнь)
```

Надо создать словарь, где ключами являются названия языков, а значениями - слова из списка.

Примерно так:

```
dict={'eng': word, 'rus':компьютер}
```

для каждого слова соответственно.

Comment: Во-первых, мне так и не удалось понять, по какому алгоритму из такого списка должен получиться такой словарь — куда пропали слова music, sky, жизнь? Во-вторых, это выглядит как учебное задание — что вы пытались сделать и почему у вас не получается?

Comment: Это всего лишь пример того,как должен выглядеть итог,тут нет попыток.Пока что моя голова не в силах понять,как сделать это.

Comment: Тогда начнём с азов. Вы какой-нибудь учебник по Python читали?

Comment: Да все не так уж и плохо,спокойно строю графики,работаю с массивами,строками,записями файлов и прочим.Учусь на втором курсе ,но преподаватель не доносит нужного количества информации,увы.Не откажусь от вашего совета ,что можно почитать.Но с этим заданием не знаю,что делать.И да,Вы правы:оно учебное :)

Comment: В таком случае необходимо уточнить, в чём именно проблема. Не можете задать список? Не можете создать словарь? Не знаете, как отличить русское слово от английского? Не знаете, как последовательно обработать каждое слово в списке? Если вы не можете всё из перечисленного — вам нужно читать учебники. Если что-то одно — добавьте соответствующее уточнение в вопрос. // И приведите более внятный пример, потому что я до сих пор не понял, почему в словаре оказались именно `word` и `компьютер`, а не `sky` и `жизнь`.

Comment: А на выходе программы что должно получится?

Comment: Покажите список слов.

Comment: И вообще какая логика?

Comment: Словарь возвращает значение по ключу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данное задание выполнимо только при изменении некоторого условия: слова будут ключами, а язык -- значением. Дело в том, что (насколько мне известно) язык Python не поддерживает более одного значения для одного ключа. Вот ниже предоставлен код, который является решением вашей задачи, при новом условии:

```
WordsList = ["word", "music","sky","компьютер","жизнь"] #Список изначальных слов
WordsDict = {} #Требуемый словарь
EnglishLetters = list ("bdDfFgGhiIjJklLmnNqQrRsStuUvVwWYzZ") #Англиские буквы, которые внешне отличаются от русских
RussianLetters = list("бБвгГдДёЁжЖзЗиИйЙклЛмМнпПтУфФцЦчЧшШщЩъЪыЫьЬэЭюЮяЯ") #Русские буквы, которые внешне отличаются от англиских
EnglishWords = []
RussionWords = []
Eng = 0 #Это 2 служебные переменные для подсчета русских и англиских букв
Rus = 0
for i in WordsList: #Поочередный скан элементов списка
   Eng = 0
   Rus = 0
   LettersList = []
   for t in i: # Поочередный скан букв слова
            if  t in EnglishLetters: #Проверка буквы -- является ли англиской?
                      Eng += 1
            if t in RussianLetters: #Проверка буквы -- является ли русской?
                      Rus += 1
   if  Eng > 0 and Rus == 0:
        EnglishWords.append(i)
   if  Rus > 0 and Eng == 0: 
        RussionWords.append(i)
WordsDict = dict.fromkeys(RussionWords, "rus")
WordsDict.update(dict.fromkeys(EnglishWords, "eng"))
print(WordsDict)
```

Плюс этой программы в том, что в изначальный список можно вписывать новые слова и он будет работать
Самое главное это то чтобы слово можно было определить внешне к одному из двух языков. Иначе слова просто не будет в словаре. Кстати, хочу сказать что все слова типа: "312312" или "%" или "ttyutффыфыффЭ" также не будут отражаться в словаре. 
Давайте разберем программу: 
   1. В начале создаются все необходимые для работы списки, словари и
    переменные. Я в коде оставил комментарии чтобы было понятнее.
    Кстати, функция list создает список из текста по букве. К примеру
    после выполнения `l = list("LIST")`. В итоге список равен `["L","I","S", "T"]`. 
 
     2. Сканируем наш список. Чтобы разобраться в сканировании посмотрите материалы про циклы (а конкретно про `for`)
     3. Сканируем каждую букву элемента, проверяем её на наличие в списках `EnglishLetters` и `RussianLetters`, меняем переменные в
    зависимости от результата (чтобы в дальнейшем понять к какому языку
    пренадлежит).
     4. Далее проверяем размеры переменных `Eng` и `Rus`, затем по результам проверки условием помещаем слово в один из двух списков (`EnglishWords`,`RussionWords`)
     5. После этого элементы  одного списка поочередно вставляем как как ключи со значением "rus". (команда `dict.fromkeys()`). Делаем тоже
    со вторым списком, но команда  `dict.fromkeys()` будет находиться в
    другой -- `update()`, которая отвечает за *добавление* новых значений
    с их ключами к словарю. Плюс к этому вместо "rus"  пишем "eng". В
    заключении выводим словарь на экран.

@Чайник, рекомендую порчитать статьи по:
 циклам 
 спискам 
 условиям 
 словарям 
 и картежам 
Также попрошу разобраться в коде, прочитать объяснение и комментарии.
Спасибо за интересный вопрос.

Comment: Это что-то прекрасное!Спасибо, Вы гений :)